# Curl doesn't update database

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to update my online database with the offline version. The following code executes without giving an error code but the expected result is not showing.  Any help will be really appreciated as series of Google searching proved abortive.

```
 <?php
 include("inc_files/inventory.php");
 // update sales_rec records

 $get_sales_rec = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales_rec WHERE status = '0'      ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
 while($rec = mysql_fetch_array($get_sales_rec)){
 $id = $rec['id'];
 $receipt = $rec['receipt'];
 $customer = $rec['customer'];
 $total = $rec['total'];
 $amount = $rec['amount'];
 $balance = $rec['balance'];
 $discount = $rec['discount'];
 $date = $rec['date'];
 $time = $rec['time'];
    ? $type = "sales_rec";
 $ch = curl_init();   // initiate curl
 $url = "http://www.sample.com/inventory/test.php"; // where you want to post data
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // tell curl you want to post something
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "type=$type&r=$receipt&c=$customer&t=$total&a=$amount&b=$balance&d=$discount&dt=$date&ti=$time"); // define what you want to post
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in string format
 $output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute
 curl_close ($ch); // close curl handle
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: You may need to provide more details.  For instance, how are you checking for success?  Are you sure that there are records to be selected in the source database?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried passing an array

```
$data = array('name' => 'aaa', 'title' => 'dev');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```